# ¿Cómo trasladar el foco (focus) a un input de mi modal con VueJs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

Estoy tratando de cambiar el foco automáticamente cuando se muestra mi modal. lo intenté de varias formas pero ninguno me funciono.

Alguna idea de como puedo hacerlo? , este es mi modal.

```
<div id="modal" class="modal fade" :class="{'mostrar' : modal}" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" style="display: none;" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-primary modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title" v-text="tituloModal"></h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" @click="cerrarModal()" aria-label="Close">
                  <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <select class="form-control col-md-3" v-model="criterioA">
                            <option value="nombre">Nombre</option>
                            <option value="descripcion">Descripción</option>
                            <option value="codigo">Código</option>
                            </select>
                            <input type="text" id="input" v-model="buscarA" @keyup.enter="listarArticulo(buscarA,criterioA)" class="form-control" placeholder="Texto a buscar" data-modalfocus autofocus="autofocus">
                            <button type="submit" @click="listarArticulo(buscarA,criterioA)" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-search"></i> Buscar</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-sm">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Opciones</th>
                                <th>Código</th>
                                <th>Nombre</th>
                                <th>Categoría</th>
                                <th>Precio Venta</th>
                                <th>Stock</th>
                                <th>Estado</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr v-for="articulo in arrayArticulo" :key="articulo.id">
                                <td>
                                    <button type="button" @click="agregarDetalleModal(articulo)" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">
                                    <i class="icon-check"></i>
                                    </button>
                                </td>
                                <td v-text="articulo.codigo"></td>
                                <td v-text="articulo.nombre"></td>
                                <td v-text="articulo.nombre_categoria"></td>
                                <td v-text="articulo.precio_venta"></td>
                                <td v-text="articulo.stock"></td>
                                <td>
                                    <div v-if="articulo.condicion">
                                        <span class="badge badge-success">Activo</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div v-else>
                                        <span class="badge badge-danger">Desactivado</span>
                                    </div>

                                </td>
                            </tr>                                
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" id="cerrarModal" class="btn btn-secondary" @click="cerrarModal()">Cerrar (ESC)</button>
                <button type="button" v-if="tipoAccion==1" class="btn btn-primary" @click="registrarPersona()">Guardar</button>
                <button type="button" v-if="tipoAccion==2" class="btn btn-primary" @click="actualizarPersona()">Actualizar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
```

probé de con estos códigos que pongo mas abajo.

```
$(window.document).on('shown.bs.modal', '.modal', function () {
    var timer = window.setTimeout(function () {
        $('#input', this).focus();
        typeof timer !== 'undefined' && window.clearTimeout(timer);
    }.bind(this), 100);
});


$("#modal").on('show', function(event){
            window.setTimeout(function(){
              $(event.currentTarget).find('input#input').first().focus()
            }, 0175);
          });


$(document).on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
   $(this).find('.form-control:visible:first').focus();
});
```

también probé con la propiedad de `autofocus`. y con código simple en JS como estos

```
$('#input').focus();
document.getElementById('input').focus();
```

Y otros muchos mas que encontré por la red. Alguna ayuda de porque no me esta funcionando con nada? Estoy trabajando con Laravel y Vuejs

Comment: ¿Donde está añadiendo los métodos que intentó?

Comment: en una etiqueta script de mi componente. Al principio de todo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En primer lugar para `VueJs`, se aconseja utilizar [nextTick()](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-nextTick) en lugar de `setTimeout`, `nextTick` se efectuará cuando existe algún cambio en el DOM.

Como tiene una variable `booleana`  `this.modal` para saber cuando mostrar su modal, puede escuchar el cambio de esta con [watch()](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#watch).

Además la selección por id, puede hacerlo también con [refs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref), que dará una referencia al elemento y así añadir el focus respectivo.

```
 <input type="text" id="input" v-model="buscarA" 
      ref="input" 
      class="form-control" placeholder="Texto a buscar">


watch: {
  modal(){
    if(this.modal){ // modal mostrada
         Vue.nextTick().then(()=> this.$refs.input.focus());
    }
            
  }
},
```

[Ejemplo](https://jsfiddle.net/hx3zymdc/)

Comment: ten en cuenta el tab-index no se si en vue afecta eso

Comment: @JackNavaRow afectar en qué sentido ?

Comment: https://www.w3.org/WAI/UA/TS/html401/cp0101/0101-TABINDEX.html

Comment: Tengo que aprender mas sobre Vuejs entonces... Tu respuesta funciono para mi... Gracias